# How to display up to two digits at max but can show less?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I format a cell in a grid that is treated like text to be zero, one, or two digits depending on what the value is but to cut it to two digits if it has more?

If the value is 25 we display 25.
If the value is 26.3 we display 26.3.
If the value is 27.59 we display 27.59.
If the value is 28.124 we display 28.12.
If the value is 11.1111111 we display 11.11.

Does this make sense?

I'm using C#, MVC, and javascript/jquery.

Comment: `yourValue.ToString(".##")` will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to round the value, you can do two different things:

```
//using String.Format()
string.Format("{0:#.##}", someValue)
//using ToString()
someValue.ToString("#.##")
```

Working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YYV9fo)

If your value is not in a double/decimal then you can either manipulate the string by checking the index of the decimal point and trimming the string to 1 or 2 indexes to the right of that.  However it might just be easier to parse the value into a new double then let the string formatting take it from there.

Comment: If I try either of those it doesn't work. It keeps the text with 3 decimal places at 3. Is this because it is text? Does the format only work if I'm transforming a decimal type?

Comment: Okay I used your way but had to do double.parse also beforehand. I wanted to accept both of cnuts answer and yours but figured yours was the most helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can user Math.Round function

```
decimal d = 28.1234;
Var a = Math.Round(d,2);
```

a will be 28.12

Comment: I don't think OP wants to actually truncate the value, but rather just display the value with a maximum number of decimal points.

Comment: Yes. That's true. @maccettura has already answered on how to format a string and I have given example on how to round the value and display until 2 decimal points. It's question owner wish which one to use, which will meet his requirements.

Answer (score 1):

So because you said it's like a text you start with a string :

```
string text = "25.1234";
```

Then you can parse it to a double so you can round it :

```
double number = double.Parse(text);
```

Then you finish by rounding the value to the decimal you need and transforming it to a string :

```
text = Math.Round(number, 2).ToString();
```